# how to check multiple row in DevExpress CheckEdit

Tags: c#, devexpress

This is my code

```
gridView1.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn()
        {
            Caption = "Selected",
            ColumnEdit = new RepositoryItemCheckEdit() { },
            VisibleIndex = 1,

            UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean

        });
```

But I cant check multiple checkEdit at the same time.
Why was that?
And please show me the way out.
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your requirement? You want to be able to create a checkbox at the Grid to enable the user to Select many rows, so that after this you can retrieve wich rows are selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are two answers to that question, one very simple, and one very complex, let's start with the simple:

If you want to have an column that has the "Selected" caption and act as a checkbox to indicate that a particular record was selected, you have two options:

1) If you can alter the class in your data source to add a property that is bool and could be used with DataBinding, then, all is done in a very simple way, jast add the property and bind the data and it will work:

```
    class SimplePerson
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }

    BindingList<SimplePerson> source = new BindingList<SimplePerson>();

    void InitGrid()
    {

        source.Add(new SimplePerson() { Name = "John", IsSelected = false });
        source.Add(new SimplePerson() { Name = "Gabriel", IsSelected = true });

        gridControl.DataSource = source;
    }
```

2) You cannot alter you classes, so you need to this by signing the correct grid events and drawing the column yourself, and also adding the right handlers for all the actions.... is a very complex case, but for your luck i have this done, because i have had this problem in the past, so i will post you my full class!

```
   public class GridCheckMarksSelection
{

    public event EventHandler SelectionChanged;

    protected GridView _view;
    protected ArrayList _selection;
    private GridColumn _column;
    private RepositoryItemCheckEdit _edit;

    public GridView View
    {
        get { return _view; }
        set
        {
            if (_view == value)
                return;
            if (_view != null)
                Detach();
            _view = value;
            Attach();
        }
    }

    public GridColumn CheckMarkColumn { get { return _column; } }
    public int SelectedCount { get { return _selection.Count; } }

    public GridCheckMarksSelection()
    {
        _selection = new ArrayList();
    }

    public GridCheckMarksSelection(GridView view)
        : this()
    {
        this.View = view;
    }

    protected virtual void Attach()
    {
        if (View == null)
            return;
        _selection.Clear();
        _view = View;
        _edit = View.GridControl.RepositoryItems.Add("CheckEdit") 
            as RepositoryItemCheckEdit;
        _edit.EditValueChanged += edit_EditValueChanged;
        _column = View.Columns.Insert(0);
        _column.OptionsColumn.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
        _column.VisibleIndex = int.MinValue;
        _column.FieldName = "CheckMarkSelection";
        _column.Caption = "Mark";
        _column.OptionsColumn.ShowCaption = false;
        _column.UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.Boolean;
        _column.ColumnEdit = _edit;
        View.CustomDrawColumnHeader += View_CustomDrawColumnHeader;
        View.CustomDrawGroupRow += View_CustomDrawGroupRow;
        View.CustomUnboundColumnData += view_CustomUnboundColumnData;
        View.MouseUp += view_MouseUp;
    }

    protected virtual void Detach()
    {
        if (_view == null)
            return;
        if (_column != null)
            _column.Dispose();
        if (_edit != null)
        {
            _view.GridControl.RepositoryItems.Remove(_edit);
            _edit.Dispose();
        }
        _view.CustomDrawColumnHeader -= View_CustomDrawColumnHeader;
        _view.CustomDrawGroupRow -= View_CustomDrawGroupRow;
        _view.CustomUnboundColumnData -= view_CustomUnboundColumnData;
        _view.MouseDown -= view_MouseUp;
        _view = null;
    }

    protected virtual void OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectionChanged != null)
            SelectionChanged(this, e);
    }

    protected void DrawCheckBox(Graphics g, Rectangle r, bool Checked)
    {
        var info = _edit.CreateViewInfo() as CheckEditViewInfo;
        var painter = _edit.CreatePainter() as CheckEditPainter;
        ControlGraphicsInfoArgs args;
        info.EditValue = Checked;
        info.Bounds = r;
        info.CalcViewInfo(g);
        args = new ControlGraphicsInfoArgs(info, new GraphicsCache(g), r);
        painter.Draw(args);
        args.Cache.Dispose();
    }

    private void view_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Clicks == 1 && e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            GridHitInfo info;
            var pt = _view.GridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
            info = _view.CalcHitInfo(pt);
            if (info.InRow && _view.IsDataRow(info.RowHandle))
                UpdateSelection();
            if (info.InColumn && info.Column == _column)
            {
                if (SelectedCount == _view.DataRowCount)
                    ClearSelection();
                else
                    SelectAll();
            }
            if (info.InRow && _view.IsGroupRow(info.RowHandle) 
                && info.HitTest != GridHitTest.RowGroupButton)
            {
                bool selected = IsGroupRowSelected(info.RowHandle);
                SelectGroup(info.RowHandle, !selected);
            }
        }
    }

    private void View_CustomDrawColumnHeader
        (object sender, ColumnHeaderCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column != _column)
            return;
        e.Info.InnerElements.Clear();
        e.Painter.DrawObject(e.Info);
        DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, e.Bounds, SelectedCount == _view.DataRowCount);
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void View_CustomDrawGroupRow
        (object sender, RowObjectCustomDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        var info = e.Info as GridGroupRowInfo;
        info.GroupText = "         " + info.GroupText.TrimStart();
        e.Info.Paint.FillRectangle
           (e.Graphics, e.Appearance.GetBackBrush(e.Cache), e.Bounds);
        e.Painter.DrawObject(e.Info);
        var r = info.ButtonBounds;
        r.Offset(r.Width * 2, 0);
        DrawCheckBox(e.Graphics, r, IsGroupRowSelected(e.RowHandle));
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void view_CustomUnboundColumnData
        (object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column != CheckMarkColumn)
            return;
        if (e.IsGetData)
            e.Value = IsRowSelected(View.GetRowHandle(e.ListSourceRowIndex));
        else
            SelectRow(View.GetRowHandle(e.ListSourceRowIndex), (bool)e.Value);
    }

    private void edit_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _view.PostEditor();
    }

    private void SelectRow(int rowHandle, bool select, bool invalidate)
    {
        if (IsRowSelected(rowHandle) == select)
            return;
        object row = _view.GetRow(rowHandle);
        if (select)
            _selection.Add(row);
        else
            _selection.Remove(row);
        if (invalidate)
            Invalidate();
        OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public object GetSelectedRow(int index)
    {
        return _selection[index];
    }

    public int GetSelectedIndex(object row)
    {
        return _selection.IndexOf(row);
    }
    public void ClearSelection()
    {
        _selection.Clear();
        View.ClearSelection();
        Invalidate();
        OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void Invalidate()
    {
        _view.CloseEditor();
        _view.BeginUpdate();
        _view.EndUpdate();
    }

    public void SelectAll()
    {
        _selection.Clear();
        var dataSource = _view.DataSource as ICollection;
        if (dataSource != null && dataSource.Count == _view.DataRowCount)
            _selection.AddRange(dataSource);  // fast
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < _view.DataRowCount; i++)  // slow
                _selection.Add(_view.GetRow(i));
        Invalidate();
        OnSelectionChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public void SelectGroup(int rowHandle, bool select)
    {
        if (IsGroupRowSelected(rowHandle) && select) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < _view.GetChildRowCount(rowHandle); i++)
        {
            int childRowHandle = _view.GetChildRowHandle(rowHandle, i);
            if (_view.IsGroupRow(childRowHandle))
                SelectGroup(childRowHandle, select);
            else
                SelectRow(childRowHandle, select, false);
        }
        Invalidate();
    }

    public void SelectRow(int rowHandle, bool select)
    {
        SelectRow(rowHandle, select, true);
    }

    public bool IsGroupRowSelected(int rowHandle)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _view.GetChildRowCount(rowHandle); i++)
        {
            int row = _view.GetChildRowHandle(rowHandle, i);
            if (_view.IsGroupRow(row))
                if (!IsGroupRowSelected(row))
                    return false;
                else
                    if (!IsRowSelected(row))
                        return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool IsRowSelected(int rowHandle)
    {
        if (_view.IsGroupRow(rowHandle))
            return IsGroupRowSelected(rowHandle);
        object row = _view.GetRow(rowHandle);
        return GetSelectedIndex(row) != -1;
    }

    public void UpdateSelection()
    {
        _selection.Clear();
        Array.ForEach(View.GetSelectedRows(), item => SelectRow(item, true));
    }
}
```

And now you need to know how to use this:

```
    void InitGrid()
    {
        gridControl.DataSource = source;

        // Do this after the database for the grid is set!
        selectionHelper = new GridCheckMarksSelection(gridView1);
        // Define where you want the column (0 = first)
        selectionHelper.CheckMarkColumn.VisibleIndex = 0;
        // You can even subscrive to the event that indicates that 
        // there was change in the selection.
        selectionHelper.SelectionChanged += selectionHelper_SelectionChanged;
    }

    void selectionHelper_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something when the user selects or unselects something
    }
```

But how do you retrieve all the selected items? There is a example assuming that the type bond is 'Person'

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Return all selected persons from the Grid
    /// </summary>
    public IList<Person> GetItems()
    {
        var ret = new List<Person>();
        Array.ForEach
            (
                gridView1.GetSelectedRows(), 
                cell => ret.Add(gridView1.GetRow(cell) as Person)
            );
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: It seems like the person that asked the question didn't really needed! All the effort and adding a very nice classto handle the sittuation perfectly and the guy does not even come back to check the answer.... i wonder if its worth doing this.....

Comment: oh, very sorry for my late reply. I've solved this problem but my internet has been in trouble. After days I sinked in anothers code part. Thank you so much, Gabriel. :)